# Rust error expected type `()` found type `(i32, i32)`

Tags: for-loop, rust, numbers, tuples

Pretty new to Rust, decided to brush up using the [Advent of Code 2020 Day 1 Puzzle](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1). I'm using the following function:

```
fn find_numbers_2020(v: Vec<i32>) -> (i32,i32) {
    let mut n1: i32 = 0;
    let mut n2: i32 = 0;
    let mut cnt = 0;
    let size = v.len();
    for v_i in v {
        n1 = v_i;
        cnt = cnt+1;
        for i in cnt..size {
            if (n1 + *v.get(i).unwrap()) == 2020 {
                n2 = *v.get(i).unwrap();
                (n1, n2) //Issue is here
            }
        }
    }
    (n1, n2)
 }
```

But I get the error
"32 (n1, n2)

```
     ^^^^^^^^ expected (), found tuple.
```

It's being called from main as follows

```
fn main() {
     let filename = String::from("./input.txt");
     let v = parse_file(filename); //This works fine
     for v_i in v {
          println!("{}", v_i);
     }
     let result = find_numbers_2020(v);
     let (n1, n2) = result;
     println!("{} + {} = {}", n1, n2, n1+n2);
     println!("{} * {} = {}", n1, n2, n1*n2);
}
```

I should also mention that `v` is a `Vec<i32>`. Sorry for the beginner question but Rust can be a little confusing and I haven't been able to find any answers through googling.

Comment: Sorry for rough formatting, I don't typically ask questions on here. Go easy on me please (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the `return` keyword only if the returned value is the last expression in the function block, otherwise you need to explicitly use `return`. Adding `return` to your example fixes that particular error but a bunch of new ones come up in its place. This is how I'd write the function:

```rust
fn find_numbers_2020(v: Vec<i32>) -> (i32, i32) {
    for (skip, &n1) in v.iter().enumerate() {
        for &n2 in v.iter().skip(skip) {
            if n1 + n2 == 2020 {
                return (n1, n2);
            }
        }
    }

    panic!("no pair of numbers in vec sum to 2020");
}
```

Comment: Few more errors after like you mentioned but I was able to clean it up. Thanks so much for the explanation, I had no idea return statements worked like that!

Comment: @OverwhelmedByMath glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it by clicking on the gray checkmark underneath the answer score, thanks!

Comment: Done, sorry still new around here!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where you need to use a [`return` expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/return-expr.html). Your initial [`for` loop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html) also consumes `v`, so to be able to do [`v.get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get) in the inner loop, you need to borrow `v` instead, i.e. `&v` or [`v.iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter).

```rust
fn find_numbers_2020(v: Vec<i32>) -> (i32, i32) {
    let mut n1: i32 = 0;
    let mut n2: i32 = 0;
    let mut cnt = 0;
    let size = v.len();
    for &v_i in &v {
        n1 = v_i;
        cnt = cnt + 1;
        for i in cnt..size {
            if (n1 + *v.get(i).unwrap()) == 2020 {
                n2 = *v.get(i).unwrap();
                return (n1, n2);
            }
        }
    }
    (n1, n2)
}
```

This is also a perfect case of when you could return an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) and use an [`if let` expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/if-expr.html#if-let-expressions). So instead of returning `(i32, i32)` then you would return `Option<(i32, i32)>`.

Instead of doing `*v.get(i).unwrap()`, then you can also just [index `v`, i.e. `v[i]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html).

```rust
fn find_numbers_2020(v: Vec<i32>) -> Option<(i32, i32)> {
    let mut cnt = 0;
    for &n1 in &v {
        cnt += 1;
        for i in cnt..v.len() {
            if (n1 + v[i]) == 2020 {
                let n2 = v[i];
                return Some((n1, n2));
            }
        }
    }
    None
}

fn main() {
    // ...

    if let Some((n1, n2)) = result {
        println!("{} + {} = {}", n1, n2, n1 + n2);
        println!("{} * {} = {}", n1, n2, n1 * n2);
    }
}
```

Instead of manually incrementing indices, you can use [`enumerate()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) in the first loop, then in the second loop you can use [`skip(i + 1)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) with the index returned by [`enumerate()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate).

```rust
fn find_numbers_2020(v: Vec<i32>) -> Option<(i32, i32)> {
    for (i, &n1) in v.iter().enumerate() {
        for &n2 in v.iter().skip(i + 1) {
            if (n1 + n2) == 2020 {
                return Some((n1, n2));
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

Instead of `v: Vec<i32>`, it would be more idiomatic to use a slice, i.e. `v: &[i32]`. In `main()` you just have to borrow `v` in your `find_numbers_2020()` call, i.e. `find_numbers_2020(&v)`

Comment: Great, advice! I always appreciate tips and opportunities to learn, thank you!

Comment: @OverwhelmedByMath You're welcome, happy I could help :)